# Smart Search translation

Tags: joomla-4.x, language, smartsearch

In Joomla 4.4.2 the Smart Search component translation doesn't work for any other language then english but it happens only for 6 translations:
COM_FINDER_ADVANCED_TIPS_AND;
COM_FINDER_ADVANCED_TIPS_INTRO;
COM_FINDER_ADVANCED_TIPS_NOT;
COM_FINDER_ADVANCED_TIPS_OR;
COM_FINDER_ADVANCED_TIPS_OUTRO;
COM_FINDER_ADVANCED_TIPS_PHRASE;
When I try to modify them from ini file doesn't work.
Someone knows why.

Comment: Do the translations exist in the language file for your language?

Comment: Yes it is. The web site has now tree languages. English, French and Italian.

Comment: If the translations are there then there may be a bug in Smart Search and perhaps an issue could be raised to highlight it?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.
I have three files com_finder.ini and the english one (52 lines) is different then others (58 lines). The six lines cited are missing inside it, but the output it's only that.

Comment: Ensure all quotes inside these strings are properly escaped like `\"`. Otherwise, ini translation won't work.